# CookieXSRFStrategy not working in AOT mode @angular

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular2-http

I am providing `CookieXSRFStrategy` for `XSRFStrategy`  in **app.module.ts**

```
providers: [
    { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/order/' },
    { provide: XSRFStrategy, useValue: new CookieXSRFStrategy('csrftoken', 'X-CSRFToken') },
    { provide: RequestOptions, useClass: DefaultRequestOptions }
  ],
```

working fine with watch/serve on second build but when building with --prod flag, getting this error:

> ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically.
>   Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or
>   lambda with a reference to an exported function (position 50:34 in the
>   original .ts file), resolving symbol AppModule in
>   E:/repo/src/app/app.module.ts

**ng --version**

```
@angular/cli: 1.0.0
node: 6.9.1
os: win32 x64
@angular/common: 4.0.0
@angular/compiler: 4.0.0
@angular/core: 4.0.0
@angular/forms: 4.0.0
@angular/http: 4.0.0
@angular/platform-browser: 4.0.0
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.0.0
@angular/router: 4.0.0
@angular/animations: 4.0.0
@angular/cli: 1.0.0
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.0.0
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Answering my own question, found that I have to use a reference to an exported function, so using like:

```
providers: [
    { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/order/' },
    { provide: XSRFStrategy, useValue: cookieStrategy },
    { provide: RequestOptions, useClass: DefaultRequestOptions }
],

export function cookieStrategy() {
  return  new CookieXSRFStrategy('csrftoken', 'X-CSRFToken');
}
```

compiled well, but was giving runtime error: as

> ERROR TypeError: this._xsrfStrategy.configureRequest is not a function

changing **useValue** in provide to **useFactory** fixed the problem

```
providers: [
    { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/order/' },
    { provide: XSRFStrategy, useFactory: cookieStrategy },
    { provide: RequestOptions, useClass: DefaultRequestOptions }
  ],
```

Comment: This is gold. You should accept the answer as well.